# Merging 3 different-Not Crossing Shapes into 1 Path

Tags: text, path, mask

I want to merge 3 letters into 1 path. Their paths simply don't touch or cross each other. So basically it means I have 3 different positioned shapes I need to merge.

Is it possible?

[image: This is the shapes.]

And the reason is, I will insert lines inside of them with a `clipping mask.` Since there are 3 separate shapes, I have to deal them 1 by 1. This is why I am trying to merge all these 3 letters into 1 path. For easy `clip masking`

But instead of this, Expanding via Object Menu, Merge and Unite via Pathfinder only converts these 3 path into a Group.

Here's an example for what I'm trying to do:
[image]

Comment: Maybe it’s just me, but I don’t understand what it is you’re trying to do. What do you mean by “insert lines inside of them with clipping mask”? Could you show an example of what you’re hoping to achieve as the final result (not just the compound path, but what you want to do with the compound path)?

Comment: I just added another image for what i m trying to do. Simply want to find an easier way to use clipping mask for multiple shapes at the same time.

Comment: Simply turn the shapes into a single compound path and using that as a clipping mask should work.

Comment: What software are you using? I was defaulting to Illustrator, but looking at your grey anchors again, I'm not so sure anymore.

Answer (score 5):

1. Select all of your shapes;
2. Select `Object > Compound Path > Make`;
3. Use the resulting path as a clipping mask.

Make sure that any compounded letter shapes are compound paths as well before trying to integrate them into the bigger path. That is, letter shapes alike a, e, b, d ,e etc. which have counters and i and j which have loose elements (the dot in case of the i and j).